# Query when is one or several values

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, themes, array

I'm trying to make filter by querying different elements from a custom post type (stores)

The problem is when I want to query the "styles", given that all stores have 2 or more instead of just one and the query is not working

```php
$style = $_GET['style'];
if(empty($style)) {
    $style = array('Casual/Décontracté','Classique','Luxe','Vintage','Street/Sports','Gothic/Underground' );
}

<div class="row"><?php
if(have_posts() ):
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'store', 
        'meta_key' => 'store_client_type' ,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'style_clause' => array(
                'key' => 'store_style', 
                'value' => $style,
            ),
        )
    ),  
);
```

Comment: Can you fix the indenting? It's very difficult to read the code with broken indentation. What do you mean by querying the styles? When you stay stores what are you referring to? A data store? A product category in a shop plugin? Use the edit link to update your question to make more sense

Comment: better like that?

Comment: I think I understand now, but are you sure that saving the styles in post meta is what you want? A styles taxonomy would be hundreds if not thousands of times faster, give you a free UI in the admin area, templates, archives, functions, even REST API endpoints all for free!

Comment: Mostly because I'm working with ACF and all my db has those values stored